# jQuery each is repeating last item twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Newish to jQuery, do not see why this is occurring.  On success, objects are returned. Each represents a users name, and profile link.  The idea is to populate a modal with related users.  Here is the code that is responsible for creating the list:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) { 
    var likeUser = $( ".user-container" ).clone();
    likeUser.find(".username-title").html(item.user_login);
    likeUser.appendTo( ".modal-body");

});
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Each user is listed once, except for the last user, which is repeated twice.  Why is this?

Additionally - If there is a smarter way to populate a list please share.  Cloning divs seems inefficient.

Comment: check data, might be it twice in collection.

Comment: I checked it using console.log(item.user_login); and no duplicates are being logged.  Also checked the array before being returned, same story.

Comment: `$( ".user-container" ).clone()` clones all the selected elements, n elements n cloned elements. Use `$( ".user-container" ).eq(0).clone()` instead. Your collection should have 2 elements and you don't see the main problem.

Comment: is your collection of only 2 items?

Comment: undefined - you were right that fixed it.  If you reply with that as an answer I will select it best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is in making clone with a class name, when first loop iterate it add an element with class name, now second time in iteration it found two elements with same class `user-container` and create a clone of both and on replace name it replace in both `username-title` causing to show it twice, if you have 3 items 3rd will show thrice.

try:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) { 
    var likeUser = $( ".user-container" ).first().clone();
    likeUser.find(".username-title").html(item.user_login);
    likeUser.appendTo( ".modal-body");

});
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```